# SQLite Select rows with not same values in two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table

```
url    lastcached lastupdate
-----  ---------- ----------
url1   0          1
url2   0          1
url3   1          1
```

I want to make a query that returns a row for every record in which lastcached and lastupdate is not same. So result should be

```
url    lastcached lastupdate
-----  ---------- ----------
url1   0          1
url2   0          1
```

This is simple question but i cant realize how to do this. Thank you!

**[Updated]**

Queries like this:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE lastcached <> lastupdate
```

is not working in this test SQLite database: yadi.sk/d/DtKHR4VsDuMhf

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE lastcached != lastupdate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select url, lastcached, lastupdate
from your_table
where lastcached <> lastupdate
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d48f1/1)

Comment: What do you mean? Why not?

Comment: Yes. Its working in sqlifiddle. But its not workig in sqlite. Here is example databse: http://yadi.sk/d/DtKHR4VsDuMhf

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE lastcached <> lastupdate
```

produces the right result

Answer (score 0):

SQL QUERY:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lastcached != lastupdate
```